# Reading Redis key-value which is JSON string using redigo

Tags: string, go, redis, redigo

I am trying to read Redis Key-val in Go. Key is string and value is JSON string. Eg- Key=

```
discov_32161296
```

and Value as Json string=

```
"{\"10283\":true,\"11064\":true,\"15123\":true,\"15447\":true,\"15926\":true,\"16530\":true,\"16537\":true,\"16799\":true,\"17088\":true,\"17249\":true,\"18501\":true,\"18529\":true,\"18601\":true,\"3044\":true,\"3687\":true,\"4926\":true,\"5483\":true,\"6\":true,\"6675\":true,\"8332\":true,\"8336\":true,\"8674\":true}"
```

Getting below error while reading in Go

```
redis.Values err redigo: unexpected type for Values, got type []uint8
```

Here's my code :

```
uIDDiscoveryOffer := fmt.Sprintf("%s_%d", "discov", uid)
opDataStr, err := redis.String(redis.Values(con.Do("GET", uIDDiscoveryOffer)))
    if err != nil || err != redis.ErrNil {
        utils.Log1("readCacheTxnByUID-Disc-redis.Values-err", fmt.Sprint("redis.Values err : ", uidDiscoveryOffer, " error: ", err.Error()))
    } else {
         //Some Logic
    }
```

Comment: How do you put Value to redis, could you show all related code?

Comment: Did you consider using RedisJSON module?

Comment: @GuyKorland Issue was due to use of redis.Values. Correct way would be which is given in the answer opDataStr, err := redis.String(con.Do("GET", uIDDiscoveryOffer))

Answer (score 2):

The Redis [`GET`](https://redis.io/commands/get) returns the value of a key. [`redis.Values()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Values) may be used to convert the result of a command that returns multiple items.

Since `GET` returns a single item, only use [`redis.String()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#String), you don't need `redis.Values()` here:

```
opDataStr, err := redis.String(con.Do("GET", uIDDiscoveryOffer))
```